# Why does my arrayList skip an element on deletion

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to delete three elements of an array (indexes 0,1, and 2) and then have the next three elements move into the indexes 0,1,2.  For some reason, the array  is not deleting the proper elements

```
       ArrayList <String> tryThis = new <String>ArrayList();
       tryThis.add("first");
       tryThis.add("second");
       tryThis.add("third");
       tryThis.add("fourth");
       tryThis.add("fifth");
       tryThis.add("sixth");
       tryThis.add("seventh");
       tryThis.add("eighth");
       tryThis.add("Ninth");

       System.out.println(tryThis.get(0) + tryThis.get(1) + tryThis.get(2));

       tryThis.remove(0);  
       tryThis.remove(1);
       tryThis.remove(2);

       System.out.println(tryThis.get(0) + tryThis.get(1) + tryThis.get(2));
```

I am expecting it to print "first, second, and third" before the removal and then print " fourth, fifth, and sixth" after. However, it prints "first second third" and then prints "second fourth sixth" after the removal.  Why?

Comment: Just do `tryThis,remove(0);`  `tryThis,remove(0);`  `tryThis,remove(0);` the 0th element changes after each removal

Comment: not that this solves anything but `<String>ArrayList()` should be `ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: Remove the first element. Remove the second element. Remove the third element. It's doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: Do not use ArrayList if you remove elements frequently.

Comment: This illustration will help to understand better . the code is working fine . Initial Elements : first , second , third , fourth , fifth , sixth , seventh , eighth , Ninth remove(0) Elements : second , third , fourth , fifth , sixth , seventh , eighth , Ninth remove(1) Elements : second , fourth , fifth , sixth , seventh , eighth , Ninth remove(2) Elements : second , fourth , sixth , seventh , eighth , Ninth Final second , fourth , sixth , seventh , eighth , Ninth

Comment: Elliott Frisch,  The first element is a string that says "first", the second "second", and the third element says "third".  When they are removed, and then the positions are printed, the first and third elements are removed but the second (the string that says "second") element remains.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting element at index 0, the former index 1 element is shifted to index 0, and so on. So you should remove at index 0 three times:

```
tryThis.remove(0);  
tryThis.remove(0);
tryThis.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `remove(0)` method changes your list by removing the first (index 0) element of it, so the indexes of all other elements are changed too. Try calling `remove(0)` three times to get the result your are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities.

You can run the following code 3 times (for example, using a for-loop):

```
tryThis.remove(0);
```

Or, you run your code in the opposite way:

```
tryThis.remove(2);  
tryThis.remove(1);
tryThis.remove(0);
```

Keep in mind that, using `remove(int index)`, it removes the element at the specified position in this list and shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

---

P.s: As already mentioned, you should use the right Syntax:

```
ArrayList <String> tryThis = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There the type is obvious (implicit, in your case and use), you can also leave the second `<String>` away:

```
ArrayList <String> tryThis = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove you remove in descending order.
From source code:
Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
     Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
      indices).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList <String> tryThis = new <String>ArrayList();
           tryThis.add("first");
           tryThis.add("second");
           tryThis.add("third");
           tryThis.add("fourth");
           tryThis.add("fifth");
           tryThis.add("sixth");
           tryThis.add("seventh");
           tryThis.add("eighth");
           tryThis.add("Ninth");

           System.out.println(tryThis.get(0) + tryThis.get(1) + tryThis.get(2));

           int i[] = {2,1,0};

           for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
               tryThis.remove(i[j]);
           }

           System.out.println(tryThis.get(0) + tryThis.get(1) + tryThis.get(2));
    }
```